# How do I make turtle stop using class and self representing a turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, python-turtle

I made this turtle in terms of self, I would really like someone who knows a lot about this topic to help me out.
The post says that my post is mostly code so I'm just spamming this sentence.
The post says that my post is mostly code so I'm just spamming this sentence.
The post says that my post is mostly code so I'm just spamming this sentence.

```
import turtle

class SuperAwesomeTurtle(turtle.Turtle):
'''a super awesome turtle!'''


    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.speedyTurtle = 0
        self.speed(1)
        self.goforward()

    def goforward(self):
        self.forward(1)
        self.getscreen().ontimer(self.goforward,40)


    def speedUp(self):
        if self.speedyTurtle > 9:
            self.speed(0)
        else:
            self.speedyTurtle += 5
            self.speed(self.speedyTurtle)

    def slowDown(self):
        self.speedyTurtle -= 5

    def turnLeft(self):
        self.left(90)
    def turnRight(self):
        self.right(90)


    def stop(self):
        self.speedyTurtle(0)


    def action(self):
        self.forward(self.speedyTurtle)


wn = turtle.Screen()
pete = SuperAwesomeTurtle()

wn.onkey(pete.speedUp, "Up")
wn.onkey(pete.slowDown, "Down")
wn.onkey(pete.turnLeft, "Left")
wn.onkey(pete.turnRight, "Right")
wn.onkey(pete.stop, "s")
wn.onkey(wn.bye, "q")

wn.listen()
while True:
    pete.action()
wn.mainloop()
```

I've tried doing some things in the stop method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the obvious issue seems to be:

```
def stop(self):
    self.speedyTurtle(0)
```

Should really be:

```
def stop(self):
    self.speedyTurtle = 0
```

But your post title is confusing.  What do you really want?  I.e. drop the "so I'm just spamming" statements in your question and describe your situation fully.

> I want the turtle to immediately stop after pressing the shortcut for
> stop, which is "s" and the thing that you have done here only makes
> turtle slow down a lot, not make it stop

Looking at your code in detail, it seems you've two issues that are causing problems.  The first is you're mixing the concept of forward distance per move (speed) with the turtle's concept of drawing speed, and adjusting/using each randomly.  Let's toss turtle's concept of drawing speed and only deal with forward distance per move.

Second, you've two different mechanisms moving the turtle forward, the `ontimer()` in `goforward()` and the infinite `while True:` loop calling `action()` calling `forward()`.  Let's eliminate the `while True:` loop, which has no place in an event driven world like turtle, and just use `ontimer()`.

The following code fixes both these problems and should roughly do what you describe:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class SuperAwesomeTurtle(Turtle):
    '''A super awesome turtle!'''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.distance = 3
        self.goforward()

    def goforward(self):
        self.forward(self.distance)
        screen.ontimer(self.goforward, 50)

    def speedUp(self):
        self.distance += 1

        if self.distance > 9:
            self.distance = 9

    def slowDown(self):
        self.distance -= 1

        if self.distance < 1:
            self.distance = 1

    def stop(self):
        self.distance = 0

    def turnLeft(self):
        self.left(90)

    def turnRight(self):
        self.right(90)

screen = Screen()
turtle = SuperAwesomeTurtle()

screen.onkey(turtle.speedUp, 'Up')
screen.onkey(turtle.slowDown, 'Down')
screen.onkey(turtle.turnLeft, 'Left')
screen.onkey(turtle.turnRight, 'Right')
screen.onkey(turtle.stop, 's')
screen.onkey(screen.bye, 'q')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I want the turtle to immediately stop after pressing the shortcut for stop, which is "s" and the thing that you have done here only makes turtle slow down a lot, not make it stop.

Comment: @crypxs, I've added a complete solution that explains and addresses the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.